# How to get values to dense table with columns of categories using PostgreSQL (crosstab)?

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I have this toy example which gives me sparse table of values separated in their different categories. I would want to have dense matrix, where all columns are individually ordered.

```
drop table if exists temp_table;
create temp table temp_table(
    rowid int
    , category text
    , score int
    );
insert into temp_table values (0, 'cat1', 10);
insert into temp_table values (1, 'cat2', 21);
insert into temp_table values (2, 'cat3', 32);
insert into temp_table values (3, 'cat2', 23);
insert into temp_table values (4, 'cat2', 24);
insert into temp_table values (5, 'cat3', 35);
insert into temp_table values (6, 'cat1', 16);
insert into temp_table values (7, 'cat1', 17);
insert into temp_table values (8, 'cat2', 28);
insert into temp_table values (9, 'cat2', 29);
```

Which gives this temporary table:

| rowid | category | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | cat1 | 10 |
| 1 | cat2 | 21 |
| 2 | cat3 | 32 |
| 3 | cat2 | 23 |
| 4 | cat2 | 24 |
| 5 | cat3 | 35 |
| 6 | cat1 | 16 |
| 7 | cat1 | 17 |
| 8 | cat2 | 28 |
| 9 | cat2 | 29 |

Then ordering score values to different columns based on their category:

```
select "cat1", "cat2", "cat3"
from crosstab(
    $$ select rowid, category, score from temp_table $$ -- as source_sql
    , $$ select distinct category from temp_table order by category $$ -- as category_sql
 ) as (rowid int, "cat1" int, "cat2" int, "cat3" int)
```

That outputs:

| cat1 | cat2 | cat3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 |  |  |
|  | 21 |  |
|  |  | 32 |
|  | 23 |  |
|  | 24 |  |
|  |  | 35 |
| 16 |  |  |
| 17 |  |  |
|  | 28 |  |
|  | 29 |  |

But I would want the result of the query to be dense, like:

| cat1 | cat2 | cat3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 21 | 32 |
| 16 | 23 | 35 |
| 17 | 24 |  |
|  | 28 |  |
|  | 29 |  |

Maybe PostgreSQL's crosstab is not even right tool to do this, but that comes to my mind first as it produces that sparse table close to the result I would need.

Comment: What makes 21 in `cat2` to be on same row with  32 on `cat3` and not some other of the possible values? Is it ordered by `rowid` or `score`?

Comment: In the final wanted result, the "32" is in the first row just because it is the first value in cat3 category. Imagine, that after I've got a dense table of values, I can use LibreOffice calc to easily draw line diagrams of these three categories in the same graph.

Comment: "It is first" *when sorted on which column*? Relational databases do not guarantee you get rows in any particular order, unless you sort them.

Comment: In this toy example, I happen to have accidentally values in order, but in the real case they are not ordered. I know how to order the values in the sparse result table already, by adding "order by score" in the crosstab()'s "source_sql" parameter.  The problem is, how to get from the sparse result table to the dense result table then.

Comment: Also, is the number of columns (`cat1` .. `cat3`) fixed, since you have them spelled out in your query or should this be dynamic?

Comment: Even better if number of categories could be dynamic. But in the real use case I know the number of categories. I can replace "select cat1, cat2, cat3" with "select *" to have unknown number of categories, but in the crosstab:s syntax, after "as" I think I need to know the number of categories and their type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for the exact given example data and expected output.

```
select max(cat1), max(cat2), max(cat3) 
from crosstab(
$$ select rank() over(partition by category order by rowid) as ranking, 
  rowid, 
  category, 
  score 
from temp_table 
order by rowid, category asc$$ -- as source_sql
, $$ select distinct category 
from temp_table 
order by category $$ -- as category_sql
  ) as (ranking int, rowid int, "cat1" int, "cat2" int, "cat3" int) 
group by ranking 
order by ranking asc
```

You can test the solution here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f198e40a18a282cc0d65fa6ecdf797cb

Edit:
Improvements made to your query to arrive at the solution:

1. In the source SQL query, I have ranked the category values based on the rowid order, which helps "determining" the order of the expected values, as per your requirement.

`select rank() over(partition by category order by rowid) as ranking, rowid, category, score from temp_table order by rowid, category asc`
[image: Ranking over Categories]

2. In the external query, I am effectively picking the `max()` values of each category, for each of the rankings as obtained in the source SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
  select category, score, row_number() over (
    partition by category order by score
  ) as r
  from temp_table
)
  select
    sum(score) filter (where category = 'cat1') as cat1,
    sum(score) filter (where category = 'cat2') as cat2,
    sum(score) filter (where category = 'cat3') as cat3
  from cte
  group by r
  order by r
;
```

If the number of columns is known and it is reasonably small, `FILTER` might be a better option than `CROSSTAB`, which requires an extension.

Comment: Yes, good point, to able to make it without extension also. I learned a lot from both solutions. They are not really obvious ways to use SQL; both using aggregate methods and partitions.